# Call the Bigquery stored procedure in Dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have written a stored procedure in Bigquery and trying to call it within a dataflow pipeline. This works for the `SELECT` queries but not for the stored procedure:

```
pipeLine = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
rawdata = ( pipeLine
            | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
               query="CALL my_dataset.create_customer()", use_standard_sql=True)
          )
          pipeLine.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_dataset.create_customer()
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM `project_name.my_dataset.my_table` 
    WHERE customer_name LIKE "%John%"
    ORDER BY created_time
    LIMIT 5;
END;
```

I am able to create the stored procedure and call it within the Bigquery console. But, in the dataflow pipeline, it throws an error while calling it:

> "code": 400,
> "message": "configuration.query.destinationEncryptionConfiguration cannot be set for scripts",
>
> "message": "configuration.query.destinationEncryptionConfiguration cannot be set for scripts",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalid"
>
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

**Edit:
Is there any other method in beam that I can use to call the stored procedure in bigquery** ?

I see multiple threads raised on the same issue, but did not find answer for it, so thought to post this question. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you explain your use case for calling stored procedure in Apache Beam pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

The principle of a procedure is to perform a job and to return nothing. The principle of a function is to perform a job and to return something.

You can't use a stored procedure as a read from in Dataflow, your error is normal. The parametrized views are in the pipe to achieve what you want. The solution for now is to use a UDF or to directly write the query in your code.

---

**EDIT 1**

What do you want to do?

- Do you want to get data? If so, it's not a procedure that you have to use.
- Do you want to simply call a Stored Procedure? If so, simply perform an API call, with the BigQuery client library to run a call query, that's all. But you have to update your stored procedure because for now, it's only a projection and it's useless "for a procedure".

Comment: If not the the Read method, is there any other method in Beam that I can use to call the stored procedure ? or there is no way at all ?